# union all in subquery only returns 1ste value - I think

Tags: mysql, sql

when running below on its own, I get 3 or whatever records back depending on the structure that is correct (the 2 queries return the parent id & all the children of that parent - so far so good):

```
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel WHERE channelid=7
UNION ALL
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel 
JOIN (SELECT @channelid:=7) tmp WHERE channelid_parent=@channelid
```

no I want the ads for those channelids - however using it as a subquery only returns 1 record (it seems)

```
SELECT marketadheading FROM marketad WHERE channelid IN (
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel WHERE channelid=7
UNION ALL
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel 
JOIN (SELECT @channelid:=7) tmp WHERE channelid_parent=@channelid )
```

am I stupid or what?

Update:

```
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel 
JOIN (SELECT @channelid:=7) tmp WHERE channelid_parent=@channelid
```

returns 1 record with a value of 11 - and there is an add with channelid 11

but running

```
SELECT marketadheading FROM marketad WHERE channelid IN (
SELECT @channelid:=channelid AS channelid FROM channel 
JOIN (SELECT @channelid:=7) tmp WHERE channelid_parent=@channelid)
```

no ads are returned so it seems the SELECTS values are not being used by the IN or the nested select is not returning values

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You are using variables to navigate a hierarchical structure.  The problem is that MySQL does not guarantee the evaluation order of expressions with variables in different parts of the SELECT statement.

Your logic, though, depends on the SELECT statement being evaluated in tandem with the WHERE -- and (I should mention as well) -- on the specific order of the rows in `channel` being evaluated.

In other words, if this ever works, you are "lucky".  There are no guarantees.

Unfortunately, there is no easy fix in MySQL; it simply has no real support for graph structures (other databases offer recursive CTEs).  You can research hierarchical data models in MySQL.  There are some methods for handling such hierarchies.  This type of query is not a reliable solution.

Comment: o bloody hell :-(

Comment: you were right added another channel - and it worked but does not include the new node - is there any way this legacy ms sql can be modified to work?

    WITH ListOfNodes AS (
    SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocationID=80
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Location.* FROM Location 
    JOIN ListOfNodes ON Location.LocationID_parent = ListOfNodes.LocationID)
    SELECT * FROM ListOfNodes

Comment: @TheunisPrinsloo That is a recursive CTE, which Gordon pointed out is not supported in MySQL